# How to create a 2d polygon that outlines group data points and overlap analysis of such euclidean or hyperspace volumes

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, pca, multivariate-testing

I have constructed a PCA plot using the ggbiplot function and added confidence ellipses (stat_ellipse) but I want to create a 2d polygon that outlines the contour of all data points of the different groups (consisting of three lakes), how can I do this?

This would later serve to analyse the % overlap between the euclidean or hyperspace 'volumes' of the three groups (lakes).

df = a correlation matrix

```
>lake2
     [1] kariba   kariba   kariba   kariba   kariba   kariba   kariba   kariba   kariba   kariba  
    [11] kariba   liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi
    [21] liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi
    [31] liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi liambezi mweru   
    [41] mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru   
    [51] mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru   
    [61] mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru   
    [71] mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru   
    [81] mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru    mweru   
    Levels: kariba liambezi mweru

>df
                specialist1   specialist2   
    species1    -0.313262597-0.437460551
    species2    0.576373454 -0.645732708
    species3    0.865365178 -0.493823505
    species4    0.183177252 -0.648027188
    species5    0.331757788 -0.356624212
    species6    0.099814746 -0.565901604
    species7    0.504824107 -0.517415651
    species8    -0.23524605 -0.074835643
    species9    0.3355018   -0.430837755


    df1<-prcomp(df)

    ggbiplot(df1, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = lake2) + theme_bw() +
      scale_color_discrete(name = '') + 
      theme(legend.direction = 'vertical', legend.position = 'right') +
      stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon",  alpha = 1/6, aes(fill = groups), show.legend = F)
```

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example by adding some (not necessarily all) data in df. Try `dput(df)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip I have included some of the data. In the entire dataset there are 14 columns and 85 rows

Comment: I found the answer in a different post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893559/r-adding-alpha-bags-to-a-2d-or-3d-scatterplot Amazing work!